# Eclipse - use OS environment variable in build path

Tags: java, eclipse

Say I have two Windows environment variables named JAVA8 and JAVA6
which point to the root folders of the respective JDKs.

Can I use the the JAVA8 Windows variable in Eclipse
(to e.g. add it the build path of a given project)?
I mean can Eclipse refer to %JAVA8% directly once it's set at the OS level?

Also, I want to make this project portable so that I can give
this project to another team member (who might be on Mac OS e.g.)
with the only requirement for him to create a JAVA8 environment
variable on his OS.

I did quite some searching on the web (incl. in SO), and this seems
impossible (but I doubt such a basic thing would be impossible).

Comment: Why do you cut your text in half? Let the browser do the text wrapping.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't know, just a habit, I find it more readable maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse expects you to define the available JDK/JREs in 'Preferences > Java > Installed JREs'. In the project Java Build Path you reference this by name rather than path so that it is independent of the actual JDK/JRE location.

You can also use 'Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments' to choose a JRE for things like 'JavaSE-1.8'. Again you can use the Execution Environment name in the Java Build Path.

Comment: When another team member opens the same project how will this work on this machine and in his eclipse? I mean, how is this portable? He will have to define then the same thing in his `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` right ? I don't think that's what I want.

Comment: He will have to define the Installed JREs in the preferences using the same names, but he will not have to change all the project build paths.

Comment: I see... Still, this approach sounds somewhat clumsy to me.

Comment: The other user won't *have* to do anything on the Execution Environments preference page, and actually, neither do you. It's mostly for resolving situations where you have more than one already set up that can represent an Execution Environment and want to change which one was chosen.